# Inserting raw (binary?) image data into mysql? (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, binary, blob

I've got a raw/(binary?) image like this:

```
ÿØÿà�JFIF��–�–�*!!!$'$ &(goes on forever);
```

when i try to insert this into mysql it doesn't work, the column type is set to longblob, any ideas?

Comment: What is the encoding of your database?

Comment: Show us your php code and we may be able to provide more insight

Comment: i can't set the encoding for a longblob, but karim79's solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to escape that using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) before inserting into the database.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string` for php_mysql
`mysqli_real_escape_string` or prepare statement for php_mysqli